# Three.js StereoEffect

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've no idea why it doesn't work.
I add:

```
var effect = new THREE.StereoEffect(renderer);
effect.eyeSeparation = 10; 
effect.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
console.log("aspect is " + window.innerWidth /window.innerHeight);
```

and into function animate:

```
effect.render(scene, camera);
```

[I've prepared an example in codepen](https://codepen.io/Freeman555/pen/yPeozN).

Comment: try adding some sort of a method that filps between the normal camera and the stereo effect, this way it's hard to see what it's supposed to render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've use [another example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=Stereo#webgl_effects_stereo) to figure out my case, result:

I added a little more code inside, like;

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
```

[I've prepared final in codepen](https://codepen.io/Freeman555/pen/yPeozN).